# West US Azure VMs Won't Start

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

9/17/15 - 9:30AM PST.

I can't get any of my Azure VMs started this morning.  What was on last night is still running but I've had nothing but "InternalError : The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request."  PowerShell and Web Portal both do not work.  I don't see any service alerts online.  Anybody else?

Comment: 1.Check if you have got any email by Microsoft regarding any upgrade/maintenance. 
2. Open azure portal>Management service Tab and set the filters for date, type and status and check if you are suspecting something.

Comment: Nothing from MS and just lists of started/failed ExecuteRoleSetOperation and ExecuteRoleOperation.  I'm hoping that this is a datacenter problem.  I was able to start one machine by dropping it to a single core.

Comment: I have seen Microsoft always sends e-mail for every upgrade/maintenance. Anyway If you want to see logs goto-
portal>Management service> set time filter, status-"failed", type-"cloud service" and cloud service name - "your cloud service name". You might get something important there.

Comment: The problem was resolved with a technician.  A resource constraint on the host cluster was the core issue.  In other words there wasn't enough disk space or CPU in whatever rack (is my understanding).  The generic error was the must frustrating piece.

Comment: Great work. You must have spent lot of time to investigate. Anyway now you can relax.